# Simulate scrolling input in UWP

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to make an app that will simulate keyboard & mouse. I've managed to this so far with `Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection` by sending `InjectedInputMouseInfo` into the `InputInjector`.

However I cannot seem to generate scrolling input, all I can do is to move the mouse and press it's buttons. Is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using the `MouseData` property. This property specifies how much should the mouse wheel scroll. What is surprising however, is that the property is defined as `uint` which would mean it is possible to scroll just in one direction. Luckily this is not the case, and if you just let negative values overflow, they will cause scroll in the right direction.

```
InjectedInputMouseInfo info = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();
info.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.Wheel;
unchecked
{
    info.MouseData = (uint)-500; //scroll down
}

InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
inputInjector.InjectMouseInput(new[] { info });
```

Unchecked block is required to avoid compile time error, because as a constant `-500` cannot be converted to `uint`. You can avoid the need to do this by introducing a local `int` variable which you then assign to the `MouseData` property instead of a constant.

### Update

I have written a short [article on my blog](http://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/%E2%80%A6/injecting-input-in-uwp-apps/) about input injection which also describes scrolling.